# How to get hex2bin and base64_encode to work in JavaScript as in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

There is a source string in hex = 6b80b4ea6ebd435cbe6068aaaf2f6715

```
<?php
$hex = '6b80b4ea6ebd435cbe6068aaaf2f6715';
echo 'hex ' . $hex . PHP_EOL;

$hex = hex2bin($hex);
echo 'hex2bin ' . $hex . \PHP_EOL;


$hex = base64_encode($hex);
echo 'base64_encode ' . $hex . \PHP_EOL;
?>
```

when using hex2bin and base64_encode , the output result is as follows

```
hex 6b80b4ea6ebd435cbe6068aaaf2f6715

hex2bin k���n�C\�`h��/g

base64_encode a4C06m69Q1y+YGiqry9nFQ==
```

when trying to do the same in JavaScript (node.js) with this code

```
let hex = "6b80b4ea6ebd435cbe6068aaaf2f6715";

console.log('hex '+hex);
console.log('hex2bin '+hex2bin(hex));
console.log('base64_encode '+Buffer.from(hex).toString('base64'));


function hex2bin(s) {

    var str = "";
    const ret = []
    let i = 0
    let l
    s += ''
    for (l = s.length; i < l; i += 2) {
        const c = parseInt(s.substr(i, 1), 16)
        const k = parseInt(s.substr(i + 1, 1), 16)
        if (isNaN(c) || isNaN(k)) return false
        ret.push((c << 4) | k)
    }
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, ret)
}
```

The result is as follows

```
hex 6b80b4ea6ebd435cbe6068aaaf2f6715
hex2bin  k´ên½C\¾`hª¯/g§
base64_encode a8KAwrTDqm7CvUNcwr5gaMKqwq8vZxU=
```

How to make the result look like in PHP ? and the final transformation was short

```
hex 6b80b4ea6ebd435cbe6068aaaf2f6715

hex2bin k���n�C\�`h��/g

base64_encode a4C06m69Q1y+YGiqry9nFQ==
```

Comment: JavaScript has `atob()` (decode from base64) and `btoa()` (encode to base64)

Comment: нет проблема не в этом, проблема в изначальной неправильной конвертации hex2bin
правильный вариант будет 
function hex2bin(exe){
   return new Buffer(hex,"hex");
}